# Avoid initializing member until required

Tags: c++, class, memory, c++11, initialization

I'm creating a generic `AtomManager<T>` container that can store `Atom<T>` objects.

```
enum State { Alive, Dead, Unused };
template<class T> struct Atom
{
    T impl;
    int index, counter;
    State state;
};
```

I want `impl` not to be on the heap, as I will store `Atom<T>` instances contiguously in the manager.

`AtomManager<T>` stores atoms in an `std::vector<Atom<T>>` like this:

```
| A | A | A | A | A | A | U | U | U | U |
```

Where `A` means alive, and `U` means unused. When the user calls `AtomManager<T>::refresh()`, all atoms with `state` equal to `State::Dead` will be moved at the end of the storage, and then they will be set to `State::Unused`. Example:

```
| A | A | A | A | A | A | U | U | U | U |

// some atoms die

| A | D | A | D | A | A | U | U | U | U |

// user calls refresh()

| A | A | A | A | U | U | U | U | D | D |

// after refresh()

| A | A | A | A | U | U | U | U | U | U |
```

To create atoms, I have a function that matches the `T` constructor signature thanks to variadic templates and constructs a `T` in the first unused atom starting from the beginning of the storage.

The problem is that `T` has to be **default-constructible** (because I call `resize()` on the `std::vector`). But that's something I don't require, as I only care about `Atom<T>::impl` when the state is either `State::Alive` or `State::Dead`. And if the atom is alive or dead, it means that the user previously constructed it using the previously mentioned variadic function.

I do, however, care about `Atom<T>::index` and `Atom<T>::counter` when the atom is unused (and `Atom<T>::impl` is garbage).

**I do not care about the state of `Atom<T>::impl` when the atom is unused.**

The compiler, however, does. I cannot use `AtomManager<T>` when `T` is not default-constructible.

I tried using an union inside `Atom<T>`:

```
union { T impl; char dummy; };
```

...but I couldn't get it to work properly.

**How can I store a `T` non-constructed uninitialized instance inside `Atom<T>`?**

I do not care about its state. I'm sure I will construct it properly before accessing it. But when the atom is unused, I want it to be in an undefined state.

**What's the best way of achieving this?** I don't want `Atom<T>::impl` to be stored on the heap.

I don't want to introduce additional dependencies. I don't need to query the state of `Atom<T>::impl` as I **know** when it's safe to access it.

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I don't want to introduce a boost dependency in the project and I don't need to check whether `Atom<T>::impl` is initialized or not. I **know** when I can access it properly or when it should be just garbage.

Comment: BYTE[sizeof(T)] + placement new?

Comment: *"but I couldn't get it to work properly."* What's the problem?

Comment: Btw you should use `std::aligned_storage` instead of byte arrays if you choose that trick.

Comment: @dyp: Could you elaborate on why I have to use `std::aligned_storage`? I've always been confused on when and why it should be used.

Comment: `std::aligned_storage<T>::type` is a POD that guarantees to be suitably aligned for `T`. This is not guaranteed for ordinary byte arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`aligned_storage`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage), [placement `new`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax) and [explicit destructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720201/calling-destructor-explicitly) calls to the rescue!

```
enum State { Alive, Dead, Unused };
template<class T> struct Atom
{
    typename std::aligned_storage<sizeof(T), std::alignment_of<T>::value>::type impl;
    T& data() { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&impl); }
    T const& data() const { return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(&impl); }

    int index, counter;
    State state;

    template<typename... V>
    void create(V&&... args)
    {
        new(static_cast<void*>(&impl))T(std::forward<V>(args)...);
        state = Alive;
    }

    void destroy() { data().~T(); state = Unused; }

    ~Atom() { if(state != Unused) destroy(); }

    Atom(Atom const& other)
        : index(other.index),
        counter(other.counter),
        state(other.state)
    {
        if(state != Unused)
            new(static_cast<void*>(&impl))T(other.data());
    }

    Atom(Atom&& other)
        : index(other.index),
        counter(other.counter),
        state(other.state)
    {
        if(state != Unused)
            new(static_cast<void*>(&impl))T(std::move(other.data()));
    }
};
```

The basic idea is to start with providing properly aligned uninitialized storage. Then, when you whish to create an object, a variadic template forwards all your arguments to a placement new expression, which will basically call the constructor on that storage. Finally, when you destroy it (or the destructor of `Atom` is called while it is not yet `Unused` again), the destructor is called so that the memory does not represent an object anymore.

The humongous copy and move constructors are needed, so that copies will map to copies of the `T`s correctly. Writing assignment operators has been omitted for brevity (such as it is).

Comment: I've used `std::aligned_storage` [in my implementation](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/49150/handle-based-entity-manager-that-stores-entities-contiguously)

Answer (score 4):

The simple answer is to use `boost::optional`, but you say you don't want that for some reason.

To roll your own optional type, you'll want a byte array, suitably aligned for `T`. In C++11 or later, that's simple:

```
alignas(T) char bytes[sizeof(T)];
```

If you're stuck with a historic dialect, then you might have to use compiler-specific extensions to specify the alignment, or just hope for the best.

Now you can create the object using placement-new:

```
T * impl = new(bytes) T(...);
```

the easiest way to access it is via a function:

```
T & get_impl() {return *reinterpret_cast<T*>(bytes);}
```

and don't forget to destroy it (but only if you created it):

```
get_impl().~T();
```

Comment: Why not `std::aligned_storage`?

Comment: I'm never sure whether this violates (strict) aliasing (3.10) or not :(

Comment: @dyp: I think you're allowed to alias character types. But I'm not quite sure either.

Comment: @dyp "Why not `std::aligned_storage`?" Because I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: Whether `T` has actually been initialized should be checked prior to calling the destructor.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like:

```
template<class T> struct Atom
{
public:
    ~Atom() { if (ptr) ptr->~T(); }

    template <typename...Ts>
    void create(Ts&&... args)
    {
        ptr = new (buffer) T(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
    }

    T* get() { return ptr; }

private:
    T* ptr = nullptr;
    alignas(T) std::uint8_t buffer[sizeof(T)];
    int index, counter;
    State state;
};
```