# Get Value of Void* C++

Tags: c++, void-pointers

I have a `void` pointer and I would like to get the content of what the pointer refers to.

```
void class :: method(void * pointer)
{
     cout<<pointer; // The address which the pointer refers to.
     cout<<?; //The content of where the pointer refers to.
}
```

The original type of `pointer` is unknown.

EDIT: The goal is to allow create a "generic method" which gets any type of argument, and do the same actions for each.
The limitation is that the method is virtual and therefore I cannot use template method.

Comment: I suspect you are abusing `void*`.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, I would like to allow sending to the method every type, and do the same actions for each. Limitation: the method is virtual and therefore I cannot use template method. Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnDibling, LOL! I would like to allow sending to the method every type, and do the same actions for each. Limitation: the method is virtual and therefore I cannot use template method. Any ideas?

Comment: Derive your classes from a common base with a pure virtual method. Pass a pointer to the base class to the function instead of void star, and call the virtual method there.

Comment: @JohnDibling, misunderstood. Would appreciate if you can post an example

Comment: What is your whole software supposed to do? Is it homework? Or some kind of interpreter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the `void*` back to its original type (ie. before it was cast to `void*`). Then you can dereference the pointer and use what it's pointing to.

Eg. :

```
void fun(void* ptr) {
    int* iptr = (int*) ptr;
    std::cout << *iptr;
}

int* iptr = new int(42);
fun(iptr);
```

One way to do this in a way that fits your specific use case, is to pass on the type information with the object using a generic type like [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/any.html) :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

class Foo {
    public :
    virtual void fun(const boost::any& obj) {
        if (typeid(int) == obj.type()) {
            std::cout << boost::any_cast<int>(obj) << std::endl;
        }
        else if (typeid(std::string) == obj.type()) {
            std::cout << boost::any_cast<std::string>(obj) << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "unsupported type" << std::endl;
        }
    }
};

int main(void) {
    Foo foo;
    int i = 42;
    std::string s = "str";
    float f = 1.1f;
    foo.fun(i);
    foo.fun(s);
    foo.fun(f);
    return 0;   
}
```

But that can get very verbose, depending on how many types you want to support.

Comment: Thanks. And if I do not know what is the original type and cannot use templates?

Comment: @yaelaviv: Then redesign your program so you can find the original type, or don't convert to `void*` in the first place. There's simply no way to identify what `void*` points to.

Comment: @yaelaviv : then you have a problem. You cannot safely dereference the `void*` pointer if you don't know its original type.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker, What if I know that the pointer is string or integer, is there a solution?

Comment: @yaelaviv : you need to know the exact type, not a vague description. If you update your question with a bit of background info on what it is that you're trying to achieve, we'll probably be able to assist you better.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. The types in C++ are (mostly) a *compile-time* property. At runtime, types are unknown (they are [erased)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure).

However, [RTTI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information) exist, notably for instances of some `class` containing *virtual* methods.

There is no possible trick in general. You could *redesign* your program by having some kind of [variant type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type), or by having a common root class from which all *your* objects inherit, etc etc, or by using [union types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) (better have your own *discriminated* unions).

Put it another way: when the compiler see a `void*` pointer, it does not even know the size of the data pointed by that pointer.

Future C++ standards might propose some [std::any](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/any) container.

Maybe you could have something like a cheap discriminated union class like

```
class Int_or_String {
   const bool isint;
   union {
     int n;
     std::string s;
   };
   Int_or_String(const int i) : isint(true), n(i) {};
   Int_or_String(const std::string &st): isint(false), s(st) {};
   ~Int_or_String() { if (isint) n=0; else 
     /*not sure*/ s.std::string::~std::string(); };
   // much more is missing
};
```

<sup>I'm not even sure of the syntax to explicitly destroy a union member.</sup>

See e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16720201/841108) on *calling destructors explicitly*

Perhaps the [Qt object model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/object.html) might inspire you. Look also into its [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qvariant.html)

The usual way is to define a root class in your program and adopt the *convention* that all your objects are inheriting this root class (or even that all your meaningful data are in objects derived from that root class). This requires a redesign of the whole thing.

So you would decide that your root class is e.g

```
class Root {
public:
  virtual void out(std::ostream&s) =0;
  virtual ~Root() =0;
  /// other common methods
};

static inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&o, const Root &r)
   { r.out(o); return o; }


class Integer : public Root {
   const int num;
 public:
   Integer(int n) : Root(), num(n) {};
   void out (std::ostream &o) { o << num ; }; 
   /// etc...
 }; // end class Num


class String : public Root {
   const std::string str;
 public:
   String(const std::string& s) : Root(), str(s) {};
   void out (std::ostream &o) { o << str ; }; 
   /// etc...
 }; // end class String
```

Comment: @BasileStarykevitch, any trick? Can't I force the content to be converted to any type? The method is indeed virtual, can you please give an example?

Comment: @BasileStarykevitch, Thanks, If I know that the pointer is string or ineger, is there a solution?