# Explicit call to destructor of template parameter type, even when instantiated on a builtin

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The C++ program (somewhat unexpectedly, at first, to me) compiles and runs fine, except for the line commented at the end of `main()`, which is a compile-time error if it is uncommented.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    int x;
};

template <typename T>
void create(char *buffer)
{
    std::cout << "creating " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    new (buffer) T();
}

template <typename T>
void destroy(char *buffer)
{
    std::cout << "destroying " << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
    ((T*)buffer)->~T();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buffer[sizeof(Foo) > sizeof(bool) ? sizeof(Foo) : sizeof(bool)];

    // create/destroy Foo via template function calls
    create<Foo>(buffer);
    destroy<Foo>(buffer);
    // now do the above explicitly...
    new (buffer) Foo();
    ((Foo*)buffer)->~Foo();

    // create/destroy bool via template function calls
    create<bool>(buffer);
    destroy<bool>(buffer);
    // now do the above explicitly...
    new (buffer) bool();
    // ((bool*)buffer)->~bool(); // oops, doesn't work

    return 0;
}
```

I gather from this that C++ (or at least g++'s idea of C++) allows an "explicit destructor call" of a template parameter type, even when manually doing the type replacement oneself results in a syntax error (since `bool` doesn't really actually have a destructor to call).

To be more explicit, the line:

```
((T*)buffer)->~T();
```

compiles and runs fine when T is instatiated on a `bool`, but doing the same thing with an actual `bool`:

```
((bool*)buffer)->~bool();
```

is a syntax error.

I'm discovered this behavior as I was doing template metaprogramming and find it a very helpful, so I'm guessing it's standard and was added specifically to handle cases like the one I have above. Does anyone know for sure if this is actually the case, and when this behavior was standardized if it is?

In addition, can anyone point to what the exact wording in the standard is that allows this, and the scope of the situations it allows? (I'm not adept at reading standardese so I have a hard time figuring this out myself.)

Comment: This is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720201/calling-destructor-explicitly) question. But I'm unsure if it is an exact duplicate.

Comment: @martin I'm asking specifically about the case where the template is instantiated on a builtin type, which I don't think the question covers actually...

Comment: When compiled in Visual Studio, I get   "error C2059: syntax error : 'type'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is indeed valid C++ (and has been since C++98, as far as I know), and known as a *pseudo-destructor call*. N4431 §5.2.4 [expr.pseudo]:

> 1 The use of a *pseudo-destructor-name* after a dot `.` or arrow `->`
>   operator represents the destructor for the non-class type denoted by
>   *type-name* or *decltype-specifier*. The result shall only be used as the operand for the function call operator `()`, and the result of
>   such a call has type `void`. The only effect is the evaluation of the
>   *postfix-expression* before the dot or arrow.
>
> 2 The left-hand side of the dot operator shall be of scalar type. The
>   left-hand side of the arrow operator shall be of pointer to scalar
>   type. This scalar type is the object type. The cv-unqualified versions
>   of the object type and of the type designated by the
>   *pseudo-destructor-name* shall be the same type. Furthermore, the two *type-names* in a *pseudo-destructor-name* of the form
>
> ```
> nested-name-specifier_opt type-name :: ~ type-name
> ```
>
> shall designate the same scalar type.

A *pseudo-destructor-name* is one of (§5.2 [expr.post]):

```
nested-name-specifier_opt type-name :: ~ type-name
nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id :: ~ type-name
~ type-name
~ decltype-specifier
```

While a *type-name* is one of (§7.1.6.2 [dcl.type.simple])

```
class-name
enum-name
typedef-name
simple-template-id
```

`bool` is not a *type-name*, so the `~bool()` version is a syntax error. Inside a template, a template type parameter is a *typedef-name* (§14.1 [temp.param]/p3), which is a *type-name*, so the `~T()` version compiles.

Comment: I've a question If according to above standard if it is valid C++ then why doesn't it compile ?

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, accepted. Just curious, what does standardese consider `bool` to be, if not a _type-name_?

Comment: @Trantorian `bool` is a *simple-type-specifier*.

Comment: @T.C. Hah, ok, thanks. Funny how that's not a subset of _type-name_, but that's standardese for you, I guess.

Comment: @T.C. is this a small bug in the language or deliberately, since destructors on *simple-type-specifiers* need not to be called explicitely?

Comment: @Trantorian To the contrary, *type-name* is a subset of *simple-type-specifier*s :)

Comment: @martin (Assuming that you mean scalar types) my guess is that it's deliberate; no point in letting people write completely useless code.

Comment: @T.C., would you mind adding the section number of `dcl.type.simple` to your answer? I find navigating the standard easier with section numbers.