# Trying to create Qt 4.7 QStrings, stuff into array of pointers

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, qstring

I have what I thought was something simple. Declarations in class header:

```
public:
    int index;          // just your vanilla integer
    QString *qspointer; // allocated array with space for 1000 pointers
    // allocation occurs first thing in class code: it's definitely  there
```

code:

```
index = 0;                        // works
qspointer[index] = new QString(); // causes error
```

alternate code

```
QString *qs;                      // works
qs = new QString();               // works
qspointer[index] = qs;            // causes error
```

The compile error in either case is:

```
"invalid conversion from QString to char"
"initializing argument 1 of 'QString& QString::operator=(char)"
```

it's a QString pointer. I have an array of QString pointers. I simply want to put the pointer *in* the array of pointers. This works fine with non-class items like int pointers, character pointers, etc. It's as if this isn't actually an array of QString pointers. But... nearby, I have this code:

```
qspointers[index].~QString(); // compiler likes this.
```

Which... if this wasn't an array of QString pointers... should cause an error. But it doesn't. I am so confused. :)

I'm clearly missing something fundamental; appreciate any pointers (hah)

Comment: `QString*` pointer points to an array of `QString`, not an array of `QString*`. `qspointer[index]` is a `QString`. Why don't you just use `QStringList` or similar, anyway?

Comment: The fact that `qspointers[index].~QString();` compiles only proves that `qspointers[index]` is a `QString`. If it were a pointer, it'd fail to compile - you'd need `qspointers[index]->~QString();`

Comment: ph, bloddy foo. :) Thank you! Forest... trees....

Comment: make it an answer, obvious as it is, it IS the answer, and I will vote it up

Comment: Also, to answer your question about QStringList, the reason is for performance. This is a realtime signal processing application. I need every cycle; direct access through a fast tree to the list is quicker. Also, this is the pattern for a number of types. Of course it's all working fine now. Thanks again.

Comment: You're already using a `QString`: a class that will happily allocate behind your back. The container those strings are in is the least of your concern unless you have **hard benchmarking results to convince yourself that you're right**. A `QVector<QString>` is no slower than managing all the storage manually if you use it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `qspointer[index] = new QString();`

`qspointer` is a pointer to QString(s), which, probably, points at an array and may be indexed. Thus, `qspointer[index]` is a `QString`. To be more precise, `qspointer[index]` expression returns a reference to `QString`. `new QString();` returns a pointer, so what you are trying to do in this line looks like

```
QString *ptr = whatever;
QString s = ptr;
```

which is obviously an error. Analogically,

```
qspointer[index] = qs;
```

has the same problem.

> I have an array of QString pointers.

Looks like you don't. `QString *qspointer;` is a pointer to an array of `QString`, not an array of pointers.

To make an array of pointers, you need something like this:

```
// Declaration:
QString **qspointer; // Pointer to pointers

// Allocation:
qspointer = new QString*[1000]; // Allocated array of 1000 pointers

// Putting a pointer into the array of pointers:
qspointer[index] = new QString();
```

Next,

> `qspointers[index].~QString();`

compiles, because calling a member by `.` is allowed for an object or a reference.

Finally, calling a destructor explicitly is usually a [bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187006/is-calling-destructor-manually-always-a-sign-of-bad-design) [idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16720201/calling-destructor-explicitly). Use `delete` for heap-allocated objects and `delete[]` for arrays. Note that having a pointer, you can't determine if it points to a single object or an array.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `QString`s are implicitly shared value classes (and also support move semantics since Qt 4.8), and that we're using C++ and not C, and the year is 2016, the last thing you should be doing is messing with pointers to strings like it was 1980s.

Here's what you want:

```
QVector<QString> strings(1000); // 1000 empty strings
strings[0] = "Foo";
strings[1] = "Bar";
strings.push_back("Moo");
Q_ASSERT(strings.back() == "Moo");
```

This would also be true if you were using `std::string`:

```
QVector<std::string> strings(1000);
// etc.
```

If your array has a fixed size, you should use `std::array` instead:

```
std::array<QString, 1000> strings;
strings[0] = "Foo";
strings[1] = "Bar";
```

Note that **none of the above code** will be slower than the way you presumably intend to do it:

```
QString *strings[1000];
strings[0] = new QString("Foo");
strings[1] = new QString("Bar");
```

But that's not all, of course. You need to ensure that the strings don't leak, and - presumably - that any unallocated strings aren't just dangling pointers. And of course you don't want anyone attempting to copy that array blindly:

```
// DO NOT EVEN THINK OF DOING IT THIS WAY!
class MyClass {
  Q_DISABLE_COPY(MyClass)
  QString *strings[1000];
public:
  MyClass() { memset(&strings, 0, sizeof(strings)); }
  // Note: calling delete with a null pointer is perfectly safe
  ~MyClass() { for (auto string : strings) delete string; }
  void setString(int index, const QString & value) {
    if (!strings[index])
      strings[index] = new QString(value);
    else
      *strings[index] = value;
  }
  QString string(int index) const {
    return strings[index] ? *strings[index] : QString();
  }
};
```

That way of doing it is horrible absolutely uncalled for in 2016. If your platform is too old to use `std::array`, use `QVarLengthArray`: it is like `std::array` that can optionally dynamically resize itself. And **store those strings by value, not by pointer!**.

The in-place lifetime management of strings you're doing by calling the destructor etc. is harrowing and has **absolutely no place outside of specialized classes that deal with resource management**. What does it mean in plain-English terms? It means that **if** you have benchmarking results that show that normal containers are somehow too slow **and** you've determined that your algorithms aren't to blame but simply need a specialized container to support said specialized algorithms **then** you should write a custom container that manages the collection of strings. And then use that container in your code, with nastiness encapsulated away. In 99.9999% of cases, you will not want to implement any such container. The standard library and Qt containers are plenty clever. Use them appropriately and you should be all set.

Comment: Kuba, what I'm doing works fine and 100% meets my needs. *That makes it 100% correct*. But thank you for taking the time to post your position.