# Unable to change the tab bitmaps in a CMFCPropertySheet with OutLook_Bar style

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, win32gui

I have an application with property sheet in outlook_bar style which I am using as a main dialog. I have created the property sheet with 3 pages on it. I have created 6 bitmaps each dimension(82,82) for displaying on the tabs.At a time 3 of the bitmaps will be used by the property sheet.

Whenever a user navigates to a new tab I would like to change the bitmap displayed on the selected tab. I have written a function ChangeImgList(int selno) below to do this.

The function  is called from the OnSetActive function of the respective property pages.When I run the code I get an "Encountered an improper argument error" at the line SetIconsList(m_shtSelImages.m_hImageList).

I  get this error when the second time this function is called.

The function is as below:

```
void AppPropSheet::ChangeImgList(int sel)
{
//m_shtSelImages is of type CImageList and m_bmpimgs[3] is an array of CBitmap
//both are members of AppPropSheet class
    
    static bool firsttime = true;
    int retval;

    if(!firsttime)
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        m_bmpimgs[i].~CBitmap();


    if (sel == 0)
        m_bmpimgs[0].LoadBitmapA(IDB_BITMAP86);
    else
        m_bmpimgs[0].LoadBitmapA(IDB_BITMAP77);

    if (sel == 1)
        m_bmpimgs[1].LoadBitmapA(IDB_BITMAP87);
    else
        m_bmpimgs[1].LoadBitmapA(IDB_BITMAP81);

    if (sel == 2)
        m_bmpimgs[2].LoadBitmapA(IDB_BITMAP88);
    else
        m_bmpimgs[2].LoadBitmapA(IDB_BITMAP79);
    

    if (!firsttime)
        m_shtSelImages.DeleteImageList();

    retval = m_shtSelImages.Create(81, 81, ILC_COLOR24|ILC_MASK , 1, 1);

    retval = m_shtSelImages.Add(&m_bmpimgs[0], RGB(128, 128, 128));
    retval = m_shtSelImages.Add(&m_bmpimgs[1], RGB(128, 128, 128));
    retval = m_shtSelImages.Add(&m_bmpimgs[2], RGB(128, 128, 128));

    //SetIconsList(m_shtSelImages.m_hImageList);
    
    firsttime = false;
    
}
//end of function
```

In the debugger I found the following :
It asserts in the SetIconsList function at line ENSURE(m_Icons.GetSafeHandle()==NULL) in afxpropertysheet.cpp

Apparently the way I am trying to change the bitmap is not provided by the framework.Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Not sure it's the cause of your problem, but what are your hoping to achieve with `bmpimgs[i].~CBitmap();` and `m_shtSelImages.~CImageList();`?

Comment: Or maybe it **is** the problem. You're calling the objects' destructor (which would imply those objects are destroyed) and then, straight after, you're using those objects, in lines like `bmpimgs[0].LoadBitmapA(IDB_BITMAP86);`. ???

Comment: ~CBitmap() is called to destroy the existing bitmap totally before reloading a new bitmap with LoadBitmap function. CImageList  has a DeleteImageList but I also found the detach and attach functions so not sure which function(s) to use.

Comment: Let me try to change the code and see if that is the problem.

Comment: Possibly useful reading: [calling destructor explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16720201/10871073)

Comment: I used CBitmap::DeleteObject(), changed the ImageList object  and removed the line SetIconsList(looks like it should be called only once). I am not still not getting the changed bitmaps.

Comment: @Adrian Mole Interesting reading about calling destructor explicitly. In my opinion member variables of an object are not really destroyed as long as the object is itself Alive in memory.It depends on what is written in the objects destructor. That's what  determines whether to call it or not.

Comment: Also replaced ~CImageList with call to DeleteImageList but it's still not working.Found a CImageList Replace function. working on it.

Comment: Try adding a call to `RedrawWindow()`?

Comment: Found a function CImageList::Replace() that is used to replace a bitmap in the ImageList. Added a call to GetTabControl()->Invalidate() and also RedrawWindow(). Please note I have removed the call to SetIconsList. Still not able to switch the bitmaps. Last Option is to get the coordinates of the tab bitmaps. No clue how to get those coordinates.

Comment: *"It crashes at `ENSURE(...)`"* - That's not a crash. It is a [failed debug assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/assertion-failed-dialog-box). It's telling you which conditions should be true, but isn't. Also, please format the code. As posted, it's hard to even follow through the function.

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. I have corrected it. Thanks to whoever corrected the mix up of code and text which I could not set right. My hunch about the assertion is that SetIconsList can be called only once.

Comment: @IInspectable Can we call SetIconsList more than once?. The first time is prior to a call to SetLook. How do I attach a Changed Image list with the propertysheet? since SetIconsList is failing.

Comment: Problem is not yet resolved. Awaiting your feedback.

Comment: Is my approach correct?. Is there any other ways I can change the bitmaps on the tabs? Tried a  BitBlt onto the property sheet but it doesn't work because it gets painted on later by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

The following code in class derived from CMFCPropertySheet class works
If there is any other way that works please let me know.

```
m_wndPane1.RemoveAllButtons();

retval=m_wndPane1.AddButton(m_bmpimgs[0], "Button one text", 10050, 0);
retval=m_wndPane1.AddButton(m_bmpimgs[1], "Button two text", 10051, 1);
retval=m_wndPane1.AddButton(m_bmpimgs[2], "Button three text", 10052, 2);

m_wndPane1.InvalidateButton(0);
m_wndPane1.InvalidateButton(1);
m_wndPane1.InvalidateButton(2);
```